# When a form loads read txt file into array

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am working on a C# application where when a form loads, I want it to read in the contents of a txt file and store it to an array.  Next, when a click a button on the form, I want the button click event to access the array.  How do I pass the array to the button click event?  My code below has an error "statusArray does not exist in current context" and is related to the reference to the array in the button click event.  What do I need to do?

Susan

```
private void btnCompleted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < statusArray.Count; i++)
        {
            if (statusArray[i].Equals("Complete"))

                lstReports.Items.Add(statusArray[i-2]);

        }
    }

    private void Reports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // declare variables
        string inValue;
        string data;
        ArrayList statusArray = new ArrayList();


        inFile = new StreamReader("percent.txt");

        // Read each line from the text file

        while ((inValue = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            data = Convert.ToString(inValue);
            statusArray.Add(inValue);

        }

        // Close the text file
        inFile.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the ArrayList as a member variable on your form as follows:

```
private ArrayList statusArray = new ArrayList();

private void btnCompleted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    for (int i = 0; i < statusArray.Count; i++)
    {
        if (statusArray[i].Equals("Complete"))

            lstReports.Items.Add(statusArray[i-2]);

    }
}

private void Reports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // declare variables
    string inValue;
    string data;

    inFile = new StreamReader("percent.txt");

    // Read each line from the text file

    while ((inValue = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        data = Convert.ToString(inValue);
        statusArray.Add(inValue);

    }

    // Close the text file
    inFile.Close();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

move your arrayList declaration outside of  `Reports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method, which makes it a class global.

You might also find a `List<string>` would be better to store your data in (strongly typed)

Answer (score 1):

An ArrayList is *not* the same thing as an Array, and if you're using .Net 2.0 or later ArrayLists are **evil**.

As for the reason why this fails: your arraylist is scoped to the Reports_Load() function.  You want to move it to the class level, and declare as a `List<string>`.

Another option if you really *want* an array is to use the File class' `.ReadAllLines()` method.

```
private string[] status;

private void btnCompleted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < status.Length; i++)
    {
        if (status[i] == "Complete")
            lstReports.Items.Add(status[i-2]);

    }
}

private void Reports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status = File.ReadAllLines("percent.txt");
}
```